# How to use Docker to obtain JDK + MySQL + Tomcat container?

Tags: docker

My target is to obtain "JDK + MySQL + Tomcat" Docker image.

Am I supposed to think to achieve this by building image like this:

```
docker build -t myImage .
```

with following Dockerfile?

```
FROM mysql
FROM tomcat
FROM openjdk
```

And then run this image like this:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 myImage
```

Should I use yaml instead? What is best practice about running tomcat and mysql server - inside yaml or by hands in console?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, You need to split your application in `microservices`, thats docker's Philosophy, And has many advantages including:

- Improved fault isolation
- Eliminates long-term commitment to a single technology stack
- Makes it easier for a new developer to understand the functionality
  of a service
- Easier upgrade management

In your case I recommend Separating `JDK`, `Mysql`, `Tomcat` in their own containers. There are Already `Library` images (Officials) available on `dockerhub`. You can use `User Defined Networks` to connect your 3 containers together.

Using `FROM` directive Multiple times will not combine images for you. The final `FROM` will take over. [Source](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13026).

Finally if you insist combining them in a single image, You should choose a base image like `Debian` and use `Run` Directives to Install required Packages and build the container.

Comment: Should I build one image and then run it? Or it is better to use `docker-compose up -d` with YAML? Does existence of YAML file means I can avoid building image explicitly?

Comment: Depends, If you need to change the image depending on your needs, you need to build it, but if u dont, you can use the `official image`. Either way you will use `docker compose` to bring up containers consistently.